# Combinatorics problem - in how many ways question (answer is provided)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> We have different 4n balls, we want to split them on 4 identical
>   boxes that each box contains n balls.
>
> In how many ways we can do that?

**Answer:**

$[(4nCn) * (3nCn) * (2nCn) * (nCn) * (n-1)^4!] /4!$

I only don't understand the $(n-1)!^4 $ and 4! part in the answer

Comment: Is it $(n-1)!^4$ or $(n-1)^4!$  I suspect the former.

Comment: @saulspatz $((n-1)!)^4$

Comment: It shouldn't be there in any event.  The correct answer is $$\frac1{4!}\binom{4n}{n}\binom{3n}{n}\binom{2n}{n}$$

Comment: @saulspatz that's what my lecturer did, the reason said was because we need to put the balls in order inside the boxes

Comment: @Mostfashma: that's a different problem then. There's nothing about the order in your text

Comment: @Alex same in my book, I thought it’s implied

Comment: You divide by $4!$ because the order of the boxes themselves doesn't matter. If the order of the balls in the boxes matters, then you should multiply by $(n!)^4$, not $((n-1)!)^4$  unless perhaps the boxes are shaped like rings, so the balls are in a circle.

Comment: @saulspatz so we calculate first the number of ways to choose balls in each box then we calculate how they are going to be sorted?

Comment: Yes, that's apparently what your teacher did.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example: imagine you have 6 balls, $ABCDEF$. The number of ways to select 3 of them is $\binom{6}{3}$, but this number includes all compliments, i.e. $ABC$ and $DEF$. If you have selected $ABC$ into Group 1, you have (automatically, so to say), put $DEF$ into Group 2, and vice versa. Since the groups are indistinguishable, you have to divide by $2!$. Now extend this to the problem you have.

EDIT: for the ordering, you need to multiply each selection by the size, i.e. in this case by $3!3!=3!^2$.